# Taking $p$ and $q$ to be the same value in paillier cryptosystem

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, number-theory, paillier

I was implementing Paillier cryptosystem when I came across the fact that as soon as I take the primes $p$ = $q$, I start getting incorrect decryption results.
As far as I can understand, when I take $p$ = $q$, the function $L(x)$ returns a fractional value instead of an integer one, meaning that in case when the primes are equal $L($$g^{\lambda}$ mod $n^{2}$) is not an integer. I also get that when the primes are equal, then $\lambda = (p-1)$, since lcm of $(a, a)$ is $a$.
Can someone explain that where do things go wrong when the primes are equal?
[Reference for the scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem)

Comment: The Carmichael function $\lambda(p^2)$ would be $=p(p-1)$.

Comment: Yeah, I know that but what if I don't take $\lambda$ as $\phi(n)$. I can take $\lambda = lcm(p-1, q-1) = p-1$ (in this case).

Comment: So, do you mean that since carmichael fucntion's value would be > $lcm$ so ($g^{\lambda}$ mod $n^2$) will not be congruent to $1$ mod $n$?

Comment: No, I mean the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) which is $\lambda(pq)=(p-1)(q-1)$ for different odd primes $p,q$. And if you take $p=q$ you should try $\lambda = p(p-1)$  where you get at least $g^\lambda-1\equiv 0 \bmod n$

Comment: But: Even if this technically would work, it is insecure because you can easily get $\lambda $ from $n$.

Comment: Thanks, got it. I meant the same thing though in the last comment. :)

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't use it. Just wanted to know the reason for it not working

Comment: Also, using $p=q$ and $\lambda(pq) = p(p-1)$ only _nearly_ works; non-zero multiples of $p$ do not decipher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Irrespective of the math, you CANNOT take $p=q$ since in this case the scheme is completely insecure. You must choose random, independent primes $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that unless I take the difference of |$p-q$| to be > than the limits of brute attacks, I can consider the implementation to be safe. Though, I am not considering NFS attacks here. I think that they might also come into play and as far as I remember, using meet-in-the-middle algorithms like baby-step-giant-step, we should take this difference to be more, since such algorithms solve integer factorization in close to $O(n^{1/4})$

Comment: No. The standard problem that has been studied is one where $p$ and $q$ are independent and random. Anything else is dangerous.